# Nhibernate 3.2 code mapping, problems with mappings to fields

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

This is not quite a question rather then answer and warning.

If you are going to use NHibernate 3.2 code mapping with fields (instead of properties for some reason). Are are likely to stumble on some blocking bugs, here are some I stumbled upon (I manged to duct tape them, but it took 10 hours to find them and fix):

https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-3049

https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-3055

So I recommend to use mapping only to properties or write mappings in HBM or use Fluent Nhibernate.